# В как бы прямую речь вклинилось авторское пояснение - оформление?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

> У одного из её предводителей – день рождения. Он привёз их всех сюда
>   накануне вечером, но из отеля они пока ещё так и не вышли. Не успели.
>   Вчера поужинали. Утром позавтракали. А тут уже и обед. Бедняга
>   официант сбивается с ног. **То не так, это не этак. Принеси! Подай!
>   Побыстрее! Калека!** Кричат они. **Почему один официант на весь
>   ресторан?!**
>
> В огромном ресторане занято два стола. Мы и они. Мы молчим.

Можно не кавычить, а скобки нарисовать? А в скобках - с прописной или со строчной?

> То не так, это не этак. Принеси! Подай! Побыстрее! Калека! (Кричат
>   они.) Почему один официант на весь ресторан?!

Так допустимо? Или рисовать классику:

«То не так, это не этак. Принеси! Подай! Побыстрее! Калека! – кричат они. – Почему один официант на весь ресторан?!»?

Или:

*То не так, это не этак* - от автора. А дальше сыплются разные реплики, - как их разбить на составные?

Но не такая она уж и прямая, эта речь...

В общем, сделайте, пожалуйста, красиво мне!

---

---

Ещё нашла [§ 137](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85/) - как бы его применить на практике?

> Если прямая речь принадлежит разным лицам, то каждая реплика
>   выделяется кавычками отдельно:
>
> а) реплики отделяются друг от друга знаком тире: *«Самовар – готов?» –
>   «Нет еще…» – «Отчего? Там пришел кто-то».* – «Авдотья Гавриловна» (М.
>   Г.);
>
> б) если одна из реплик сопровождается вводящими авторскими словами, то
>   следующая не отделяется знаком тире: *«Вы ведь вдова?» – спросил он
>   тихо. «Третий год». – «Долго были замужем-то?» – «Год и пять
>   месяцев…»* (М. Г.);
>
> в) точка и тире ставятся между репликами, принадлежащими разным лицам
>   и снабженными разными авторскими словами: *Проходя мимо, он сказал:
>   «Не забудь купить билеты». – «Постараюсь», – ответила я*; если же в
>   первой реплике имеются знаки восклицательный или вопросительный, точка
>   опускается: *Проходя мимо, он крикнул: «Не унывай!» – «Постараюсь», –
>   ответила я*;
>
> г) запятая и тире ставятся между репликами, принадлежащими разным
>   лицам, но объединенными общим авторским предложением: *Когда приказчик
>   говорил: «Хорошо бы, барин, то и то сделать», – «Да, недурно», –
>   отвечал он обыкновенно* (Г.); если же в первой реплике имеются знаки
>   восклицательный или вопросительный, запятая опускается: *Когда я
>   спросила: «Почему вы носите на спине ковер?» – «Мне холодно», –
>   ответил он*; то же при ином расположении частей авторского
>   предложения: *Когда я спросила: «Почему вы носите на спине ковер?» –
>   он ответил: «Мне холодно»* (Ток.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Повторения — они так и задуманы?
   Почему один официант на весь ресторан?! — В огромном ресторане занято два стола.
   Кричат они. — Мы и они. Мы молчим.
2. Два предложения объединила бы в одно:
   *Бедняга официант сбивается с ног — то не так, это не этак.*
3. *В огромном ресторане занято два стола.*
   Я бы использовала мн. число глагола, поменяла "ресторан" на "зал" и добавила "всего".
   *В огромном зале занят**ы** всего два стола.*
4. Фраза "он привёз их всех сюда" означает, что компания многочисленна. Почему бы все реплики не оформить отдельно? Все равно ведь толком не понятно, кому они принадлежат.

Может, такой вариант подойдет?

Бедняга официант сбивается с ног — то не так, это не этак.

— Принеси!
— Подай!
— Побыстрее!

В огромном зале заняты всего два стола.

— Калека!
— Почему один официант на весь ресторан?!

Кричат — они. Мы молчим.

Comment: Римуль, автор выбрала нижний кусочек: понравилось. Я ей посоветую и впредь многорепликовые куски текста столбиком строить.

Comment: Приятно быть пользительной.

Comment: (Заметим в скобках: автор повторил мою ошибку восприятия, пишет: возьму у Риммы Михайлов***ны***!)

Comment: Артём тоже частенько путает. Не обижаюсь. P. S. Я Вас благодарила на Мете ("Итоги 2017 года...") — там есть мое _настоящее_ имя.

Answer (score 1):

Бедняга официант сбивается с ног. То не так, это не этак. Принеси! Подай! Побыстрее! Калека!  **И почему это всего один официант на весь ресторан?!**

В огромном ресторане занято два стола. Мы и они. **Мы молчим, кричат они.**

Пояснение

Я думаю, что ничего менять не нужно, будет хуже. Здесь несобственная прямая речь, которая не нуждается в словах автора. Её лучше "перемешать" с ними.

Противопоставление "молчим — кричат" лучше обозначить отдельно.

**Другой вариант:**

То не так, это не этак. "Принеси! Подай! Побыстрее! Калека! " — кричат они. — Почему один официант на весь ресторан?!"

В огромном ресторане занято два стола. Мы и они. Мы молчим.

**Вариант с авторской вставкой мне не нравится.** В любом случае там нужны скобки. (Кричат они.) Иначе сложно объяснить конструкцию.

Пример из Тургенева. – Да, да, я знаю вас, Базаров, – повторила она. (За ней водилась привычка, свойственная многим провинциальным и московским дамам, – с первого дня знакомства звать мужчин по фамилии.)

Comment: Шарончик хитрый, это ты подсказываешь, как уйти от проблемы, но вот как ея решить? ***То не так, это не этак. Принеси! Подай! Побыстрее! Калека! Кричат они. Почему один официант на весь ресторан?!***

Comment: Нет проблемы, всё очень красиво. Ну не кавычки же здесь ставить. Несобственная прямая речь всегда украшает текст. Перемещение  автора в персонажа и принятие его точки зрения - это очень эффектный прием.

Comment: Как это "всё красиво"?! А "кричат они" как впишутся, не ездия по страничке?

Comment: Да они не там должны кричать, там и так всё ясно, кто кричит. А потом будет   противопоставление, вот оно-то (в разных местах) не очень ясное.

Comment: А они ТАМ кричат. Право имеют. Знаки?